# Pythonanywhere, how to use static files? url?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am completely new to [Pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com), I cant figure out why static files are not loading... Here is the path where I stored css and images stuff, 
i.e. `static/images/wikiLang.png` etc

```
/static/admin/  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/media    
/static/        /home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static  
/media/         /home/saadfast/WikiWorld/media
```

where as in the client side how should I use the URL?

what i have done in the `search.html`:

```
<div id="TopheaderImg">
  <img src="/home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static/images/wikiLogo.png" width="100px" style="float:middle"/>
  <br />
  <img src="/home/saadfast/WikiWorld/images/wikipediaLang.png" width="100px" style="float:middle"/>
</div>
```

why the image is not loading? what should the path or URL?

Comment: Try dropping `/home/saadfast/WikiWorld` unless your webserver is really serving from your machine's / directory (which would be a Bad Idea)

Comment: I have made the worked on django on localhost or on my machine

it runs fine with 
{% load staticfiles %} using in html page

but when working on pythonanywhere, the page loads without loading images, js,css etc...

Comment: Simply removed the error by using the static before images folder

<img src="/static/images/wikiLogo.png" width="100px" style="float:middle"/>

Answer (score 6):

PythonAnywhere dev here: I think the problem is in the paths you're using in your HTML.  The mapping

```
/static/        /home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static
```

Means that URLs with `/static/` at the start will be looked for in the directory `/home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static`.  So that means that where you have

```
<img src="/home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static/images/wikiLogo.png" width="100px" style="float:middle"/>
```

You should probably have

```
<img src="/static/images/wikiLogo.png" width="100px" style="float:middle"/>
```

Comment: exaclty! the problem was in path and it should be started with /static/, though I have solved the problem, but +1 for the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [PythonAnywhere wiki page about static files under Django](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoStaticFiles)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PythonAnywhere, but are you sure you've uploaded the files to the proper location on their server? It looks like they've got a custom file handler set up for the users, which you can briefly read up about [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/FileBrowser)

> You have a certain amount of storage on our servers in the form of a
>   home folder and a /tmp.

They say they offer certain directories, have you tried pointing to those?

Comment: yes..i placed the files in their static folder

the path looks like "/home/saadfast/WikiWorld/static"
and in the static folder i have places the image,css and js folder

Comment: they offered me 500 MB of space..out of which only 700KB is used
I dont think it is the error in space...