# Django at PythonAnywhere doesn't recognize static url

Tags: python, django, static

The problem looks similiar to the problem here:
[Pythonanywhere, how to use static files? url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592998/pythonanywhere-how-to-use-static-files-url/19635954#19635954) ,but I cannot comment there.

I've started learning Django and when everything worked on localhost that on PythonAnywhere it does not.

At *projectname*/settings.py I've set:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/home/*username*/*projectname*/Static/"
STATIC_URL = "/s/"
```

and even URL's from static folders in apps.

After trying to run

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

every file *.js, *.css and images were coppied to the *projectname*/Static folder.

But... none of them were recognized after launch of the app.
I've set

```
{% load static %}
```

used tags

```
{% static "assets/css/theme.css" %}
```

At the source code I can see the proper link to css file:

```
<script src="/s/assets/js/seen.min.js"></script>
```

And everything would be fine, but the "/s/" isn't recognized by django and it tries to find the view in urls.py. 
After opening the link to: *username*.pythonanywhere.com/s/assets/js/seen.min.js I've got standard, debug 404 page with the path of urls.py tries.

How to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: What do you mean, "s/ isn't recognized by Django"? It isn't supposed to be recognized by Django, static files need to be served by your static server.

Comment: yeah, and they're not recognized at all - it searches them at urls.py instead of serving my assets

Comment: Do you have ```django.contrib.staticfiles``` in your ```INSTALLED_APPS```?

Comment: Well, then this is a problem with your PythonAnywhere setup: you need to configure it so that `/s/` goes direct to the assets rather than via Django.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman - where is this setup available? I thought that just settings.py would do.

Comment: @schilingt yes, I have.

Comment: But it's not anything to do with Django! settings.py is irrelevant. Look in the server configuration - I've never used PythonAnywhere so I can't help you, but it must be in their admin interface somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a static file mapping on the web app. Look for the "Static files" heading on the web app tab.

From what I can tell of your setup, you'd need to put "/s/" for the URL and "/home/*username*/*projectname*/Static/" for the directory.

Comment: There is now a [PythonAnywhere wiki page about static files under django](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoStaticFiles)